# Swift Concurrency: Combine TaskGroup and AsyncStream?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency, asyncstream, swift-taskgroup

### Context

Suppose I want to download 300 images in the background using Swift Concurrency. I'd like two things:

1. As much parallelism as possible.
2. My caller to receive each image as it's downloaded, rather than waiting for all of them to finish.

### Approach:

`TaskGroup` has [many advantages](https://forums.swift.org/t/taskgroup-vs-an-array-of-tasks/53931/2): great parallelism, very cheap child tasks, and cancellation. But it does not return until all 300 child tasks have finished.

`AsyncStream` lets me return images as they're downloaded, but has no parallelism on its own—downloads happen one at a time, in sequence.

### Question:

What I'd like to do is wrap a `TaskGroup` with an `AsyncStream`, like this:

```
let stream = AsyncStream(NSImage.self) { continuation in
    
    _ = await withTaskGroup(of: NSImage.self, returning: [NSImage].self) { taskGroup in
        
        let imageURLs: [URL] = ... // array of 300 URLs to download
        for imageURL in imageURLs {
            taskGroup.addTask { await downloadImage(url: imageURL) }
        }

        for await result in taskGroup {
            continuation.yield(result)
        }

        continuation.finish()
        return []
    }
}
```

But `AsyncStream` can't take an `async` closure. So what's the best way to achieve this behavior with Swift Concurrency?

Comment: @Joakim - if you follow the link in my post, someone explains why `TaskGroup` is better than a bunch of child tasks created in a loop. They are not the same at all. TaskGroup is much more efficient. And the example is contrived; it's easier to use "download images" rather than explain that I'm accessing local video files, grabbing a screenshot of various frames, and returning those images.

Comment: @Sweeper Useful! I'm away from Xcode, so I'll update the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you would bridge from the synchronous context of `AsyncStream` to Swift concurrency by creating a `Task` for the asynchronous work. Also remember to add an `onTermination` closure so that it will respond to the cancelation of the `AsyncStream`:

```swift
func images(for urls: [URL]) -> AsyncStream<NSImage> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        let task = Task {
            await withTaskGroup(of: NSImage.self) { group in
                for url in urls {
                    group.addTask { await self.downloadImage(url: url) }
                }

                for await image in group {
                    continuation.yield(image)
                }

                continuation.finish()
            }
        }

        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Obviously, since you are doing all of these network requests concurrently, you must recognize that these will likely not finish in the order corresponding to the original array of URLs.

So, you might return a tuple of the original URL and the resulting image:

```swift
func images(for urls: [URL]) -> AsyncStream<(URL, NSImage)> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        let task = Task {
            await withTaskGroup(of: (URL, NSImage).self) { group in
                for url in urls {
                    group.addTask { await (url, self.downloadImage(url: url)) }
                }

                for await tuple in group {
                    continuation.yield(tuple)
                }

                continuation.finish()
            }
        }

        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps an index number and the image:

```swift
func images(for urls: [URL]) -> AsyncStream<(Int, NSImage)> {
    AsyncStream { continuation in
        let task = Task {
            await withTaskGroup(of: (Int, NSImage).self) { group in
                for (index, url) in urls.enumerated() {
                    group.addTask { await (index, self.downloadImage(url: url)) }
                }

                for await tuple in group {
                    continuation.yield(tuple)
                }

                continuation.finish()
            }
        }

        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this function

```
func downloadImage(url: URL) async -> NSImage {
    ...
}
```

You can update your code this way

```
let stream = AsyncStream(NSImage.self) { continuation in
    Task(priority: .background) {
        await withTaskGroup(of: NSImage.self) { taskGroup in
            
            let imageURLs: [URL] = ...
            for imageURL in imageURLs {
                taskGroup.addTask { await downloadImage(url: imageURL) }
            }

            for await result in taskGroup {
                continuation.yield(result)
            }
            
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it this way

```
for await image in stream {
    print("Image received")
}
```

> Of course consider the order the image appears in this last for loop is no guaranteed to be the same you follow when invoking `downloadImage(url:)`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your statement regarding TaskGroup: `But it does not return until all 300 child tasks have finished` is correct.

Here is an example code that downloads a number of images. It clearly shows that the view
displays the images as they are downloaded, not when they are all downloaded.

You can use this approach to achieve your requirements.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var images = [PhotoImg]()
    
    func loadImages() async  {
        let url1 = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-100kb.png"
        let url2 = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-200kb.png"
        let url3 = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-500kb.png"
        let url4 = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-1mb.png"
        
        let urls = [url1,url2,url3,url4]
        
        // get all images concurrently
        return await withTaskGroup(of: (Int, UIImage).self) { group -> Void in
            for i in 0..<urls.count {
                if let url = URL(string: urls[i]) {
                    group.addTask { await (i, self.loadImage(url: url)) }
                }
            }
            for await value in group {
                Task{ @MainActor in
                    print("-----> \(value.0) downloaded")
                    images.append(PhotoImg(key: value.0, img: value.1))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage(url: URL) async -> UIImage {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) { return img }
        }
        catch { print(error) }
        return UIImage()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    @State var isDone = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isDone {
                Text("All images fetched")
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
            List(vm.images) { picture in
                Image(uiImage: picture.img)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 111, height: 111)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await vm.loadImages()
            isDone = true
        }
    }
}

struct PhotoImg: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var key: Int
    var img: UIImage
}

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let images: [String]
}
```

Note, you can easily convert this code to use the `Observation` framework if preferred.